# Proving one-to-one and onto

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I am learning how to prove a function is one-to-one and onto. On some of the other threads in math stackexchange I noticed a proof:

Assume $f(m,n)=f(m',n')$. To show from this that $(m,n)=(m',n')$.
Then through some algebra you solve the function to show $n=n'$ and $m=m'$.

I understand that it shows that the function is one-to-one. But I do not understand how this proves that a function is also onto.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe the above shows that $f$ is onto. You must show that for any $y$ there exists a $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: The mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ mapping $x$ to $x+1$ is one-to-one but not onto.

Comment: Hm... you are right. But I have used the above several times in my algebra class. Maybe it is true for certain groups, but not for sets in general.

Comment: It's true for finite sets but not for infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

To show that a function is one-to-one, you may show that whenever $f(x) = f(x')$, $x = x'$. But this technique has nothing to do with showing that $f$ is onto.

To show that a function is onto, you may show that for every $y$, there is an $x$ satisfying $f(x) = y$ and to do that, you may solve $f(x) = y$ for $x$. For example, suppose $f(x)=x^3$. We solve $x^3=y$ for $x$, getting $x=\sqrt[3]{y}$. As $\sqrt[3]{y}$ is defined for all $y$, we have shown that $f$ is onto.

Comment: Yes I agree with both of you. I did not see any proof for onto either. But I don't understand what you mean by "solve f(x) = y for x"

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Cool. But is this proof scalable....like if a function had 3 or 4 variables instead of the two that you gave in your example?

Comment: You could treat the variables as a single vector and solve in the same way as in my example. But even in relatively simple cases the math can get very messy. I'm not sure there is one general and computationally simple approach to showing a multivariate function is onto.